# Files in emma report did not match any file in SonarQube Index

Tags: ant, sonarqube, emma

I'm using Jenkins,Ant to build Android app and Sonar to show reports.

It shows Unit Test Success result on Sonar ok but Unit Test Coverage not.

I configure Sonar Android Plugin to file coverage.em to show Emma code coverage and Jenkins's log shows:

```
[sonar:sonar] 14:35:45.657 WARN  - Class with name : X.co.Y.Z.gamecenter.network.base.XXX was not found in SonarQube index
...

[sonar:sonar] 14:35:45.691 WARN  - Matched files in report : 0%
[sonar:sonar] 14:35:45.691 WARN  - 21 files in emma report did not match any file in SonarQube Index :
```

But Jenkins Emma plugin shows the result normaltlly!?

How to configure Sonar to get right code coverage?

Any help is appreciated.Thank in advance!